# Why are so many people on this site so rude?

Tags: discussion

This site has some of the rudest people I've ever encountered. If whoever knew the answers I would hope they wouldn't be asking the questions. Why do you feel the need to answer so hateful?  Those of you that take the time to comment on to belittle others need to find hobbies. 
Thank you to those of us with kind words and useful suggestions!!

Comment: Please provide examples of hatefulness on the site, and then flag them for review.

Comment: @RonJohn Wammie24 would need 15 rep to flag.

Comment: Do you have any examples for this claim?

Comment: @RobertLongson good to know.

Comment: I've seen a lot of chat sites in the past 30+ years and Stack is the tamest one that I have ever seen.  IMO, I think that it's over moderated, almost to the point of neutering personality.  If you think that it contains the rudest people ever then either you're hypersensitive or you haven't experienced many web sites.

Answer (score 14):

People on this site don't get paid, and they're not here as a favor to you - they don't even know you! They come mainly because they find it enjoyable to discuss their area of interest. They write answers because they enjoy writing explanations on this topic, and also because they like the affirmation from other similar users in the form of upvotes.

What people ignore is that not every question is fun to answer even if you know the answer. And you can give an answer that is completely useless to the asker, while still having fun. So the self-appointed money experts, the regular users of this site, can get what they want either way. They can enjoy writing a helpful answer, or they can enjoy writing a rude and condescending answer that doesn't help you. It comes down to which will be more interesting to them.

If you ask a question that:

- Is extremely trivial
- Can easily be answered by simply googling it
- Has been answered already on this site
- Is illogical
- Challenges established culture of this site's regulars (for example, cheating your business partner may be a profitable move but don't expect anyone on this site to be supportive of it)
- Is not respectful to the expert
- Does not play to the expert's ego

Chances are the nice answer will not be very fun. The mean answer will be. You may agree or disagree with this, and I'm not saying it's right. But it is fundamental human nature - if you want an expert to share his expertise with you for free, you must make it as enjoyable as possible for the expert to interact with you.

Comment: Good answer. We align fairly well, and you are certainly more polite than I. IMO This site, this collection of sites doesn't exist to answer particular answers with salient questions, it is supposed to be a user generated repo of useful questions and their answers - because such a site would be useful to society. Some people miss that fact and behave as if this is a run-of-the-mill ask an expert site. Users are not here to get a service, they are doing the site a service by asking a question. If the question is poor, the service was poor and the resulting answer will be poor.

Comment: You forgot questions that are incomprehensible, and those that ask the "wrong" question (where they ask about something peripheral to what they really want to know about).

Comment: Oh, I suspect this person is not complaining about people who answer questions but the army of commenters we have.

Comment: @quid - I, as a member, are anti-comment. If I were the programmer, I’d make comments disappear in 24 hrs. Here, and on other stacks, comments are where 95% of the ill-will is created. And yet, some members feel that comments are part of this community, and wouldn’t be happy if we just kept wiping them out.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, I agree with you, and I've stopped answering questions because I don't want to deal with the comments.  But this answer is about question answerers, the problem here is the people who leave comments but rarely, if ever, answer questions. It should be frowned upon that people drive by to vomit out an opinion but never put their internet points at risk by answering a question.

Comment: With no example, I only know this new member asked one question and it got some comments and was then closed. I can’t know what, exactly, triggered the question.

Answer (score 12):

At the time you posted this question, you were a member here for 3 days, and visited twice. The one question you asked was closed, as it was off topic. That can’t have been a pleasant first experience. And, no, it would not be reasonable for us to ask every new member to first take the tour, or read the FAQ before posting. I don’t think members comments on that question were rude, but then again, “this question doesn’t belong here” can’t leave a new member feeling good, regardless.

The site is mostly member-run, when comments or answers are unkind, members can flag and mods will address the issue.

No doubt, some people have an edge, a cynical tone, etc, or there are times that otherwise friendly sarcasm isn’t taken kindly. Words, when read, don’t always come off as intended. I lean towards giving people the benefit of the doubt.

That said, I do hope you visit again, search for questions with tags that are on topics that interest you. There are over 25,000 questions posted here. Whatever your age, marital status, income, etc, there is advice that will make you money, save you money, help you avoid mistakes, and most importantly, help convince you that as a group, we are really smart, helpful, and kind.

Comment: Why is not reasonable to expect new users to read the [tour] or glance at the [FAQ] before posting? If more people did that, there'd be fewer crap questions asked.

Comment: Because, as much as I’d like that to occur, history (I’ve been a member since the beginning, and a mod soon after) and human nature tell me that’s not going to happen. For me, it’s easier to forgive and understand, than to berate.

Answer (score 8):

That sounds like a rather unkind thing to say about a site full of people who donate their time for the public good.

While there are some who post derogatory remarks, the vast majority are simply trying to help where their expertise is relevant.

Stack Exchange divided up its site into separate communities so that each community can be focused on well-defined topics. It also requires answers to be objectively correct, which in turn imposes obligations on questions that are asked.

If you find comments or answers that run counter to the good will that the site intended, feel free to raise a flag for the moderators to take a look and, if appropriate, to take action.

Note also that the site intends to be a permanent repository of good answers to questions that pertain to specific topics. However, what constitutes a ‘good’ answer is left to the community to decide - that’s what the up/down voting is for. Likewise for whether a question fits within the ‘on-topic’ guidelines listed in the help section.

Questions that are off-topic or that aren’t sufficiently well-posed to get an authoritative answer don’t really help others. In Stack Exchange, these questions can be voted to be placed on hold for awhile so that they can be edited and improved. If that editing process doesn’t help, the status of those questions switches to ‘closed’.

Questions that are already in the repository don’t need copy-paste answers. The site provides a mechanism to close such questions as duplicates that point to places containing answers.

Since all this is run by people (and almost all of it is by volunteers and visitors such as you and me), sometimes things do go wrong. The PF&M Meta site is the place to air grievances and otherwise ask questions about the main PF&M site.